# Wordpress: Functions outside of functions.php or a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a client site who won't allow access to `functions.php` or allow the addition of new plugins.

I'm trying to add some functions for an AJAX call but so far they won't work unless they are added straight into `functions.php` (on my dev site).

I have them in a file called `custom-functions.php`. I am including this file on relevant pages with:

`include get_theme_file_path( '/path/custom-functions.php' );`

I have tried adding this to the top of my custom functions file:

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/path/wp-blog-header.php');
```

But the function are not working. I get a 400 bad request from the AJAX call.

Comment: What's up with this WP installation where you can apparently edit the `wp-blog-header.php` but cannot modify functions.php, or install a plugin? Technially, if you have write access everywhere (through ssh/sftp) you can in fact install a custom plugin uploading it and programmatically enabling it through `activate_plugin` - even if the client site has `FS_METHOD` not set to `direct`. Messing around in some blog header file isn't a very clean approach.

Comment: I'm not messing around with the file, just calling it. And yes, I could technically install a plugin only to have it removed by the team looking after the site.